# Is it possible to display the Administrative tools as Tiles?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen, admin-tools

Windows 8 seems to have a few interesting Administrative tools at: **Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools**

Is it possible to display them as Tiles in the Start screen. I understand, it is possible to create the Titles manually but is there are a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In the Start Screen, use the right-side hot corners and open the charms bar. Click *Settings* and then *Tiles*. Then it will give you the option of displaying Administrative Tools as tiles.

Comment: All I see when I press Win+I or otherwise open the charms bar settings is: "Settings, Desktop (disabled), Control Panel, Personalization, PC Info, Help" I'm an administrator, but it's joined to a domain with no Win8 specific policies yet. Am I just missing something?

Comment: @SilverbackNet You have to click *Settings* and then you can see *Tiles*.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but I see the problem: I was doing it from Desktop. You have to do it from Start; a completely different menu shows in Desktop. (I should have read your answer more carefully.)

Comment: @SilverbackNet Ah, yes. The Settings menu from the Charms bar is context-sensitive, depending on what Metro app is open (or if you're on the Desktop).