# How do I add Administrator Tools to the Windows 8 Start Screen?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to display the Administrative tools as Tiles?](https://superuser.com/questions/494253/is-it-possible-to-display-the-administrative-tools-as-tiles)

As a frequent user of the administrator tools how can I add them to the Start screen for quick access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Administrative Tools, open Settings either using the upper right corner hot spot or by pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. Next, select Tiles and move the Show administrative tools slider to the right. The Start screen will be populated with many of the familiar administrative tools you know and love.