# Windows 10 - Show Administrator Tools on Windows Start Screen

Tags: windows-10-preview

As a user of Windows 10, I want to see the Administrator Tools on Windows Start Screen.

There seems to be a few Q&A for Windows 8 (see links below), but I can't find a solution for Windows 10.

- [Is it possible to display the Administrative tools as Tiles?](https://superuser.com/questions/494253/is-it-possible-to-display-the-administrative-tools-as-tiles)
- [How do I add Administrator Tools to the Windows 8 Start Screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/502263/how-do-i-add-administrator-tools-to-the-windows-8-start-screen)

Comment: Can't you pin it via Control Panel? If not then try `REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V StartMenuAdminTools /T REG_dWORD /D 1 /F` with a logoff+logon or a reboot.

Comment: You should be able just create a shortcut then pin the shortcut to the Start Menu.  You do it exactly like you do it on Windows 7.  Control Panel -> Right Click on Administrator Tools -> Create Shortcut -> Then do the additional step of pinning that shortcut to the start screen

Answer (score 2):

Then, on the Start Screen, choose the option that says "Windows Administrative Tools".

Wallah!  It's already there.  You simply needed to notice it, and click on it.

If you want to see the folder, the fast way is:

- Start Screen
- Left-click on "Windows Administrative Tools"
- Right-click on one of the icons within that section
- On the shortcut menu that shows, hover over "More", and then choose "Open file location".

Comment: (Answer tested on Windows 10 Home Version 1607 OS Build 14393.222)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the Windows Administrative Tools is already on the start menu by default but it is under All apps section and you have to scroll all the way down as it is alphabetically placed.

There are two ways to do it:
First: 
-Open File Explorer
-Click on view
-check the "show hidden items" box.
-Navigate to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
-Right click on Administrative Tools folder and click on Pin to Start
Note:
Do not forget to uncheck the "hidden items" box when done.

Second:
-Right click on the task bar
-Click on Toolbars
-Click on New toolbar
Open File Explorer
-Click on view
-check the "show hidden items" box.
-Navigate to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
-Click on Windows Administrative Tools
-Click on Select Folder
-This displays the content of the Administrative Tools Folder by the system tray

Note:
Do not forget to uncheck the "hidden items" box when done.

The second method is recommended because although the first one pins the Windows Administrative Tools to the start menu, you have to scroll down to see it and it is only added as a shortcut that takes you to the folder and you do not want that.